# Have dynamic columns in external tables

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

My requirement is that I have to use a single external table in a store procedure for different text files which have different columns.

Can I use dynamic columns in external tables in Oracle 11g? Like this:

```
create table ext_table  as select * from TBL_test              
                organization external (
                type  oracle_loader
                default directory  DATALOAD
                access parameters(                
                records delimited  by newline
                fields  terminated by '#'
                missing field values are null
                )
                location ('APD.txt')
              )
              reject limit unlimited;
```

Comment: Can you reframe the question, it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: we all know that we have to define some set of columns for external tables like create table ext_table(col1 varchar(20), col2 varchar(20))... so on . my question is that what if we want to pass columns dynamically for making an external table

Comment: Why do you have this requirement?

Comment: if you really really wanted to, you could probably create the file, create your dynamic create table statement then use dbms_sql to create the table.. but then all your queries would need to be dynamic as well. Sounds like a lot of pain.

Comment: i was trying to do something like this:  QRY1='create table ext_table_  as select * from TBL_LOGS              
                organization external (
                type  oracle_loader
                default directory  DATALOAD
                access parameters(                
                records delimited  by newline
                fields  terminated by '#'
                missing field values are null
                )
                location ('AP.txt')
  )
              reject limit unlimited;' EXECUTE IMMEDIATE QRY1;  in this i am dynemically passing table name(TBL_LOGS)

Answer (score 1):

The set of columns that are defined for an external table, just like the set of columns that are defined for a regular table, must be known at the time the external table is defined.  You can't choose at runtime to determine that the table has 30 columns today and 35 columns tomorrow.  You could also potentially define the external table to have the maximum number of columns that any of the flat files will have, name the columns generically (i.e. `col1` through `col50`) and then move the complexity of figuring out that column N of the external table is really a particular field to the ETL code.  It's not obvious, though, why that would be more useful than creating the external table definition properly.

Why is there a requirement that you use a single external table definition to load many differently formatted files?  That does not seem reasonable.

Can you drop and re-create the external table definition at runtime?  Or does that violate the requirement for a single external table definition?

Comment: i have a java code to call a procedure in oracle to insert data in different tables from different text files.In that procedure i am using external table to insert data in tables. problem is text files have different number of columns .so i was trying to change the external table columns dynemically

Comment: @puneet - But, surely, the format of the files isn't completely unknown to you.  If there is going to be some code that loads data from file1 into table1 and from file2 into table2, why can't you have separate external table definitions for each file?  Why do you need to have exactly one external table definition for all files?

Comment: actually 1 have 24 tables and text files, and i have to use single store procedure for this task.making 24 different external tables is a bit difficult

Comment: @puneet - What does the number of stored procedures have to do with the number of external table definitions?  It sounds like you need one stored procedure which calls one of 24 other stored procedures each of which uses one of 24 separate external table definitions to load data into one of 24 tables.

Comment: you are getting it wrong i said that in a store procedure i have to use a single external table with dynamic columns

Comment: @puneet - Then I'm back to my initial question-- why is there a requirement that you use a single external table definition to load many differently formatted files?  So far, I haven't seen anything that explains why that is actually a requirement.

Comment: i think  how is more important then why here

Comment: @puneet - As I've said, you can't have an external table definition with a variable number of columns.  I've laid out the alternatives if you truly want to have one external table definition.  Having one external table definition, however, is going to massively complicate the solution so understanding why you are imposing this sort of artificial limitation is important.  If you don't want to share that with us, I guess my answer stands.

Comment: earlier as i said that in a store procedure i have to use external table to insert data into tables.  there are 24 different text files from which i have to insert data into 24 different tables . one solution is that i can use if else clause and make 24 external tables       but i was thinking to do this in a simple manner by using only one external table which will have dynamic columns according to text files.every time the procedure will be called from java code(procedure will be called 24 times) it will drop external table then create it with dynamic columns as per of text file

Comment: @puneet - Is that technically possible?  Sure.  It is not obvious to me that it simplifies anything.  You'd have to use dynamic SQL to create the table definition.  You'd have to use dynamic SQL to reference the external table.  Using dynamic SQL generally makes your code more complicated, not less complicated.  And dropping and recreating objects in Oracle is generally not a good idea.  I don't see any benefit to using a single external table definition here.